# How to make changes made with xmodmap permanent

Tags: linux, keyboard, xmodmap

On my laptop, I have to enter angled brackets with

```
Fn+l for <
Fn+Shift+l for > and
Fn+AltGr+l for |
```

which is extremely awkward, so I'd like to change that to

```
AltGr+ö for <
AltGr+ä for >
AltGr+l for |
```

I've succeeded by using

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  46 = l L l L bar Lstroke lstroke"
xmodmap -e "keycode  47 = odiaeresis Odiaeresis odiaeresis Odiaeresis less dead_belowdot dead_doubleacute"
xmodmap -e "keycode  48 = adiaeresis Adiaeresis adiaeresis Adiaeresis greater dead_caron dead_circumflex"
```

I've put these commands into a shell script called by a .desktop file which is in .config/autostart. This seems to work when I reboot but when I switch to a text terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F2) and back to the X session, the mappings are lost.

I've read a lot about this topic already (overall, it is *very* confusing) and the 'proper' solution seems to involve xkb somehow (also this would work on the tty too, not only in the X session, if I understood it correctly). But I cannot figure out how to translate these xmodmap commands to the syntax the xkb-related files expect.

How can I do these mappings using xkb and make them permanent?

N.B.: I'm using openSUSE

Comment: The problem is that xkb reloads your keyboard map at various times, including coming out of screen blanker and when you change internationalization keyboard input methods.  The solution is to stop using xmodmap and translate your changes to xkb format and then tell your OS to use that instead of the default keyboard mappings for the languages you use.

Comment: Not sure how well this applies to SUSE, but it's a starting point: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions